# WSO2 Data DelegatingResultSet.isClosed in Procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wso2

i have a problem with wso2 data version 2.6.3 to execute procedure in sql server:
My Config:

```
<data name="TestDS">         
    <config id="ds_test">                  
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>                  
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://172.16.16.16:1433/db_stores;instance=sql1</property>                  
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">storeuser</property>                  
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">3st0re123</property>                  
  <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.autocommit"></property>         
</config>         
<query id="qrySearchTest" useConfig="ds_test">                  
  <sql>exec USP_PesquisaSistema  @SIS_CRIPTOGRAFIA_PASSAPORTE =:chave</sql>                  
  <result element="sistemas" rowName="sistema" defaultNamespace="http://store.test.org.br">                           
     <element name="codigoSistema" column="SIS_IDF" xsdType="xs:integer" />                           
     <element name="siglaSistema" column="SIS_SIGLA" xsdType="xs:string" />                           
     <element name="nomeSistema" column="SIS_NOME" xsdType="xs:string" />                  
  </result>                  
  <param name="chave" sqlType="STRING" ordinal="1" />         
</query>         
    <operation name="SearchTest">                  
      <call-query href="qrySearchTest">                           
         <with-param name="chave" query-param="chave" />                  
      </call-query>         
    </operation>
</data>
```

and the error **java.lang.AbstractMethodError**:

```
TID: [0] [WSO2 Data Services Server] [2012-09-24 09:44:32,762] ERROR org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} - {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet} java.lang.AbstractMethodError

    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.isClosed(DelegatingResultSet.java:688)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.isClosed(DelegatingResultSet.java:688)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processStoredProcQuery(SQLQuery.java:904)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runQuery(SQLQuery.java:2071)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:252)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.execute(CallQuery.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.execute(CallQueryGroup.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:116)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.forceExpand(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getFirstOMChild(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator._getFirstChild(OMNavigator.java:196)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.OMNavigator.updateNextNode(OMNavigator.java:140) .....
    ......
```

In the version 2.5.1 works.
If i paste the sql query without SP, works.

can help me ?
Thank

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add the version of SQL Server to your question? And what do you mean by "If i paste the sql query without SP, works" - have you tested the SP (not just the code) on the database server and does that work?

Comment: Hi, i unknown the sql version :(
just the address to db.
I tested on database server and works, and the wso2 data version  2.5.1 works too

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because in DSS 2.6.3, you require a JDBC4 driver, which only have the ResultSet.isClosed() method .. so basically download the SQL Server JDBC4 driver (sqljdbc4) and try it and see. Also, in DSS 3.0.0 (to be released), it has been fixed by making the ResultSet.isClosed optional.

Cheers,
Anjana.

Comment: Hi, thank for reply, but dont work :(
Do you have more idea ?

Comment: did you placed the Driver in the wso2_home\repository\components\lib folder?